# Regex for end of string

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't find the magic formula to get my regex working in Javascript.
let's say I have:

```
const branchnames = [
    { name:'WICO-29', key:1 },
    { name:'WICO-9', key:2 },
    { name:'wico-2', key:3 },
    { name:'wiCo-2: description', key:4 },
    { name:'WiCO-2 example ', key:5 },
    { name:'WiCO-2-dosomething', key:6 },
    { name:'wiCO-2, great', key:7 },
];
```

I would like to recover every names excepts for the first two. Hence I am looking for a regex looking for "wico-2" (not case sensitive), followed either by nothing or a non alphanumerical character. Following attempts didn't work...

```
const reg = new RegExp(/wico-2[ ,:-]?$/, "i"); // miss: 4,5,6,7
const reg = new RegExp(/wico-2\W/, "i"); // miss: 3
const reg = new RegExp(/wico-2\W?/, "i"); // wrong:1
const reg = new RegExp(/wico-2\W?$/, "i"); // only 3

branchnames.forEach( element => {
    console.log ( element.name.match(reg));
});
```

any help ? thanks !

Comment: please add the wanted result of the regex.

Comment: wait a sec.... Wico or Jico ? :D

Comment: Why you don't use `if (key > 2)`?

Comment: @Mohammad why would you? key != name

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Because *I would like to recover every names excepts for the first two*.

Comment: @Mohammad I'm not sure a key `value` in programming or in his example might be a UUID... but yeah

Comment: @Mohammad ... Actually this "key" was just used for the example, as I thought it would ease the listing of missing / wrong results in my attempts ! Sorry if it did confuse you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `/wico-2(?:\D+|$)/` to do this:

```js
const branchnames = [
    { name:'WICO-29', key:1 },
    { name:'WICO-9', key:2 },
    { name:'wico-2', key:3 },
    { name:'wiCo-2: description', key:4 },
    { name:'WiCO-2 example ', key:5 },
    { name:'WiCO-2-dosomething', key:6 },
    { name:'wiCO-2, great', key:7 },
];

const reg = new RegExp(/wico-2(?:\D+|$)/, "i"); 

branchnames.forEach( element => {
    console.log ( element.name.match(reg));
});
```

Explanation of `(?:\D+|$)`:

- Non-capturing group `(?:\D+|$)`

  - 1st Alternative `\D+` : matches any character that's not a digit (equal to [^0-9])
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - 2nd Alternative `$`: asserts position at the end of the string

Comment: @bertrand By the way, the `?:` only makes the parentheses not count as matching groups.  You could leave that out to make the regular expression easier to read, possibly at the expense of speed.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, in this case speed is clearly not an issue, and I am in favor of something easy to read / understand ... actually before the answers from the community, I was doing :

Comment: const regexp1 = currentTaskKey + '\\W'; const reg1 = new RegExp(regexp1, 'i');

   const regexp2 = currentTaskKey + '$'; // task key not followed by anything
   const reg2 = new RegExp(regexp2, 'i');

   return element.name.match(reg1) || element.name.match(reg2);

Comment: const regexp1 = currentTaskKey + '\\W';
const reg1 = new RegExp(regexp1, 'i');

const regexp2 = currentTaskKey + '$';
const reg2 = new RegExp(regexp2, 'i');

return element.name.match(reg1) || element.name.match(reg2);

Comment: (sorry for the mess... comments cannot be formatted...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as `/wico-2(?!\d)/gi`

```js
const branchnames = [
    { name:'WICO-29', key:1 },
    { name:'WICO-9', key:2 },
    { name:'wico-2', key:3 },
    { name:'wiCo-2: description', key:4 },
    { name:'WiCO-2 example ', key:5 },
    { name:'WiCO-2-dosomething', key:6 },
    { name:'wiCO-2, great', key:7 },
];
const reg = new RegExp(/wico-2(?!\d)/, "gi");

branchnames.forEach( element => {
  if(element.name.match(reg)){
     console.log (element);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your example will select also `fico-3: wico-26`

Answer (score 0):

One might do as follows;

```js
var branchnames = [
    { name:'WICO-29', key:1 },
    { name:'WICO-9', key:2 },
    { name:'wico-2hello', key:3 },
    { name:'wico-2', key:3 },
    { name:'wiCo-2: description', key:4 },
    { name:'WiCO-2 example ', key:5 },
    { name:'WiCO-2-dosomething', key:6 },
    { name:'wiCO-2, great', key:7 },
];
branchnames.forEach(bn => /wico-2(?=[^\dA-Za-z]|$)/i.test(bn.name) && console.log(bn.name));
```

Comment: like `WiCO-2-dosomething`? @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
/wico-2(([ ,:-]+|$).*$)/
```

Here is a link to regex tester:[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/DWIXjo/3)

[image]

Comment: "Don't" use spaces in regex